# How to develop logic/algorithm for a part of invoice module?

Tags: python, algorithm, code-duplication, invoice

So I am working on an Invoice Module and stuck on a logic.
Steps to generate an Invoice:

`Bringing all those rows whose cancelled_date is none or is of current_month from the database`

This gives me all the data for generating an invoice of a customer for current month.

**Pseudo Code-**

```
If membership is new:
   if (working_days/total_days) in a month is 1:
      Don't calculate prorata
   else:
       calculate pro rata(For no. of days)
else:
   calculate invoice generally
```

Now the problem is : The customer's cancelled_date can be set in above scenario like:
**Pseudo Code-**

```
If membership is new:
   if (working_days/total_days) in a month is 1:
      if cancelled_date == end_date_month:
        Don't calculate prorata
      else:
          calculate pro rata
   else:
       if cancelled_date == end_date_month:
         calculate pro rata(For no. of days)
       else:
           calculate pro rata (start_date & end_date for current                          
                      month)
else:
    if cancelled_date == end_date_month:
       calculate invoice generally
    else:
         calculate pro rata
```

How can I not make the code reduntant just by simply solving the cancelled_date scenario. I am unable to think of a good logic/algorithm for above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the problem with the algorithm you wrote, the program will only go in one path each time, so the redundency is just an aestethic problem in my opinion (and not a performence issue).

Nontheless, I can think of a different approach:

```
score = 0
If membership is new:
    score += 1
if (working_days/total_days) in a month is 1:
    score += 10
if if cancelled_date == end_date_month:
    score += 100

switch score:
    case 1: calculate pro rata (start_date & end_date for current month)
    case 11: calculate pro rata
    case 111: Don't calculate prorata
    case 101: calculate pro rata(For no. of days)
    case 100: calculate invoice generally
    case 0: calculate pro rata
```

Since you have a maximum of 3 things you need to check (is new, w/t days in a month is 1, c_date equals e_date), you can 'assign' a value for each check (1, 10, 100). Summing those values will give a unique value which you can then act upon in a switch statement. This way, you only need to write the `if` statement for each check once.

Perhaps you'll want to add a '10' case (meaning only 'w/t days in a month is 1' is true), but I'm not sure what should happen then.

Disclaimer: I don't think this is the best idea... you just asked for another algorithm.

Comment: Hey ya thanks ! This also leads to if else because code is in python. I still need to put those if/else.

Comment: sorry I did not take that into consideration

Comment: What I am thinking is make two separate functions and make a property in class for cancelled_membership and compute the invoice for both of them in different functions.